# Manter uma requisição em C# - Rest

Tags: c#, rest

A duvida que eu tenho é mais conceitual que em código.

Tenho um rest que é um serviço no servidor, o mesmo é feito em C#, gostaria que todo dia em um horário especifico ele fizesse requisição a uma URL X. Eu pensei em colocar um timer na minha aplicação dekstop feita em C# que consome o rest e chamar a url em questão, mas parei no empecilho de que o computador que consome o rest não esteja ligado. Eu consigo fazer o próprio serviço enxergar um timer dentro dele e chamar a minha URL, ou algo do tipo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não em uma api rest, o que você pode fazer é agendar essa task no servidor da aplicação ou desenvolver é um serviço do windows que ficará rodando lá. Também é possível adicionar esse job no banco de dados (caso sua aplicação e estrutura apresente algum).

Conceitualmente, como você não depende do retorno de dados na execução do método dessa API Rest, faria mais sentido a opção do windows service mas ao invés de comunicar com o seu rest, já realizar a rotina que você deseja.